# Proper way to consume NodeJS stream into buffer and write stream

Tags: node.js, stream, node-fetch

I have a need to pipe a readable stream into both a buffer (to be converted into a string) and a file. The stream is coming from `node-fetch`.

NodeJS streams have two states: paused and flowing. From what I understand, as soon as a `'data'` listener is attached, the stream will change to flowing mode. I want to make sure the way I am reading a stream will not lose any bytes.

Method 1: piping and reading from `'data'`:

```
fetch(url).then(
  response =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      const buffers = []
      const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filename)
      response.body.pipe(dest)
      response.body.on('data', chunk => buffers.push(chunk))
      dest.on('close', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString())
    })
)
```

Method 2: using passthrough streams:

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')
fetch(url).then(
  response =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      const buffers = []
      const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filename)
      const forFile = new PassThrough()
      const forBuffer = new PassThrough()
      response.body.pipe(forFile).pipe(dest)
      response.body.pipe(forBuffer)
      forBuffer.on('data', chunk => buffers.push(chunk))
      dest.on('close', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString())
    })
)
```

Is the second method required so there is no lost data? Is the second method wasteful since two more streams could be buffered? Or, is there another way to fill a buffer and write stream simultaneously?

Comment: It is actually working as expected, I was just not sure if I was lucky enough with a fast write stream. I have read a few posts saying that write steams will try to call a method `read` at their own pace (pulling), and I have also read that the 'data' listener will cause the steam to be flowing constantly (pushing)

Comment: You could just use `fs.writeFile()` if you're just going to read the whole file into memory first.  There is no need to `.pipe()` it.  If you don't need the whole file in memory, then `.pipe()` is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't miss any data, since `.pipe` internally calls `src.on('data')` and writes any chunk to the target stream.

So any chunk written to your `dest` stream, will also be emitted to `response.body.on('data')` where you're buffering the chunks.
In any case, you should listen to `'error'` events and reject if any error occurs.

And While your second mode will work, you don't need it.

---

This is a chunk of code from the [.pipe](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L660) function

```
  src.on('data', ondata);
  function ondata(chunk) {
    debug('ondata');
    var ret = dest.write(chunk);
    debug('dest.write', ret);
    if (ret === false) {
      // If the user unpiped during `dest.write()`, it is possible
      // to get stuck in a permanently paused state if that write
      // also returned false.
      // => Check whether `dest` is still a piping destination.
      if (((state.pipesCount === 1 && state.pipes === dest) ||
           (state.pipesCount > 1 && state.pipes.indexOf(dest) !== -1)) &&
          !cleanedUp) {
        debug('false write response, pause', state.awaitDrain);
        state.awaitDrain++;
      }
      src.pause();
    }
  }
```